# What do Americans call this device that provides power to multiple devices plugged into it?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

In the past I met the word power outlet, and from the context, I suspect it's the thing in the following image.

[image: device plugs into the wall and has power switch, 6 places where plugs can be inserted and two USB ports]

But recently my roommate tells me it's a "power strip". I want to know what do native Americans call this thing?